# Regular expression in C# giving wrong results

Tags: c#, regex

regular expression that I'm running: `id=(.*?)`
But it catches occurrences like

```
widget_id="dsadsadsadsadsadsa"
```

Note: There is a single whitespace in front of id. I tried adding `\s*`? at the beginning of the `re`. still no luck.

Comment: The expression matches what it's supposed to match. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I find this a great site for testing my regular expressions before I implement them. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Could you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please post the whole code related to running this regex pattern, with the exact input and expected output. Use regexstorm.net or regexhero.net to test .NET regexes, as regex101.com does not support .NET regex flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using the RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace option, as that causes the space in the pattern to be ignored.

If you must have this option, you can escape the space so the pattern would be "\ id=(.*?)".

***Update***

If you declare this in a c# string literal, then you need to escape the backslash:

```
string pattern = "\\ id=(.*?)";
```

This way, the c# compiler will unescape the double backslash to a single backslash and then the pattern as seen by regex will be "\ id=(.*?)"

Alternatively, if you declare this as a *verbatim* string literal, then this would be:

```
string pattern = @"\ id=(.*?)";
```

Comment: Then i get this error. Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: That would be c# handling the escape first.  I'll add an example of using this in a c# string.

Answer (score 1):

`\s*?` matches zero or more spaces, so it does not prevent the regex from matching prefixes in front of `id=...`.

If you want `id=...` without prefixes, use word boundary `\b` anchor, like this:

```
"\bid=(.*?)"
```

This would ensure that things like `widget_id=` are not matched. Unlike an expression with a space in front of `id`, this expression would also match `id=...` at the beginning of input.

Comment: But why does the space match an underscore, or why is the space ignored in the pattern (with `" id=..."`)? I think is what he's struggling with